# ViewModel properties stay null on HttpPost

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm completely puzzled how this simple concept doesn't seem to work. I have a ViewModel, a Controller and a View...

This is my basic ViewModel

```
public class CreateProfessionalEducationViewModel
{

    public Models.ProfessionalEducation ProfessionalEducation;

    public int ConsultantId;

    public CreateProfessionalEducationViewModel() {} // parameterless constr

}
```

These are my 2 controller methods

```
 public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        var viewModel = new CreateProfessionalEducationViewModel
        {
            ConsultantId = id
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    //
    // POST: /ProfessionalEducation/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateProfessionalEducationViewModel collection)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //db.ProfessionalEducations.Add(professionaleducation);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

and my view...

```
@model Axxes_Virtual_Resume_MVC.ViewModel.ProfessionalEducation.CreateProfessionalEducationViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ProfessionalEducation")) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>ProfessionalEducation</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducation.Year)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducation.Year)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducation.Year)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducation.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducation.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducation.Title)
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ConsultantId)
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

For some weird reason my ConsultantId is 0 and ProfessionalEducation is null in my ViewModel when posted back to the HttpPost Create method in my controller.

This should be so basic, what am I forgetting?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you invoke your action through `.../Create/1` or just `.../Create/`

Comment: Shouldn't those fields be properties instead (get;set;} ? I don't think the ModelBinder will bind to plain fields, they have to be properties.

Comment: Correct, that was my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that, the loony that is the `DefaultModelBinder` (what reconstruct viewmodels from an `HttpFormCollection`) works on properties not variables.

And if I'm not mistaken, I do believe the default model binder  don't work so well if you use inner objects like that in your Viewmodel and access their properties directly in the View.

Try something like that :

```
public class CreateProfessionalEducationViewModel
{
    public int ConsultantId  { get; set; }

    public int ProfessionalEducationYear { get; set; }

    public string ProfessionalEducationTitle  { get; set; }
}
```

And for the view of course

```
@model Axxes_Virtual_Resume_MVC.ViewModel.ProfessionalEducation.CreateProfessionalEducationViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ProfessionalEducation")) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>ProfessionalEducation</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducationYear )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducationYear )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducationYear )
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducationTitle)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducationTitle)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducationTitle)
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ConsultantId)
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

As a rule try to avoid referencing Model objects in your ViewModels (but that's just a design rule)

Answer (score 1):

Using properties instead of fields in my ViewModel fixed it for me.

Thanks to anyone for their effort.

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute of the  tags must be "ProfessionalEducation.Year" or "ProfessionalEducation.Title" in order that the default binding to work.
So use this:

```
@Html.TextBox("ProfessionalEducation.Year")
```

instead of

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducation.Year)
```

and the same for Title property.
You can read more about ASP.NET MVC Model Binding in this useful post:
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx

Comment: I used @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfessionalEducation.Year) and when checking the source it automatically gave the Name attribute the correct value :)

Comment: And having the name correct, still the binding does not work?

Comment: Have not tested your approach, but using properties instead of fields in my ViewModel fixed the issue.