# Form Data not serialized in asp.net core mvc controller model

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-core

C# model class

```
public class SubCategoryTwoViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string SubCatTwoName { get; set; }
    public CategoryViewModel Category { get; set; }
    public SubCategoryOneViewModel SubCatOne { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> File { get; set; }
    public UserViewModel AddedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }
    public UserViewModel Updated_By { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the CategoryViewModel

```
public class CategoryViewModel
    {
        public long CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddEditSubCategoryTwo(SubCategoryTwoViewModel model)
{
}
```

Here is the ajax call which use the Form Data to serialized the data send to the controller method.

```
var ajaxUrl = ApplicationRootUrl("AddEditSubCategoryTwo", "Category");
var formData = new FormData();
var totalFiles = document.getElementById("subCatFile").files.length;

for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
    var file = document.getElementById("subCatFile").files[i];
    formData.append("File", file);
}

formData.append('SubCatTwoName', self.subCatTwoName());
var category = {
    CategoryId: self.selectCategory()
};

formData.append('Category', category);
var subCatOne= {
    SubCategoryOneId: self.selectCategorytwo()
};

formData.append('SubCatOne', subCatOne);
formData.append('Active', self.active());

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    url: ajaxUrl,
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

I,am getting some field data in the controller but the java script value is not serialized to the controller model.

Here is the screenshot of the sample
 [image: Data of some field]

In the screen shot I am getting the **Category & SubCatOne field as null**. But **active, SubCatTwoName and File field has receive the value**. I want to get Category & SubCatOne  value in the controller model object. How can I achieved this.

Comment: You are appending a `javascript` object to `FormData` keys `"SubCatTwoName"` and `"Category"`. What are you expecting at server for keys `"SubCatTwoName"` and `"Category"`?

Comment: I have received the SubCatTwoName value in server side . However I, have not received the value for Category.

Comment: What does `console.log(category)` log?

Comment: Object {CategoryId: 5} This is the console output

Comment: Have not tried `asp.net-core`. Have you tried passing `category` to `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: Yes I did that also doesn't work for me. I am facing issue when I use the object. Without object it is working perfectly as you can see for active , file etc...

Comment: Why don't you use `CategoryId` and `SubCategoryOneId` as fields in you view model? this answer might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18637391/2146113 => "try to avoid referencing Model objects in your ViewModels "

Comment: I am trying to achieve this by using ajax with json object.Please can you let me know how can I achieve this by using ajax

Comment: As Guest271314 said can you check the Formdata values in the debug mode before invoking the ajax call? Try to put debugger and check whether we are passing all values to the controller.

Comment: The data in client side are good.However the server side is not bind

Answer (score 3):

Trying to add the object directly will not work. Instead you can make use of model binding by adding the nested fields with the correct name (separate the property hierarchy with dots). e.g.

```
formData.append('Category.CategoryId', self.selectCategory());
```

Comment: @Paul Hiles, does that mean we can't send json object in formData and handle it properly via model in asp.net core action?