# FormData object from React doesnt convert on backend C# to model

Tags: c#, reactjs, form-data

I have application made with React Native, and the backend API is in .NET C#. 
I am trying to send some data from frontend to backend

reactjs

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('token', token)
formData.append('document', document)
formData.append('file', file);
```

Where `token` is a string, `file` is some file, but `document` is an object with params like `Id` and `Name` . So on backend I receive the data like this

C#

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult SendDocument(string token, DocumentMobile document, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    //do thins
}
```

The problem is that object `document` is not converted to `DocumentMobile` model, like it used to do without using `FormData`, and all props inside are null.

How to do this?

Comment: can you check with the debugger what really is sent to your server via `Request.Form`, also you could try to add `[FromForm]` to your action parameters.

Comment: I checked `HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys` and there is no variable `document`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind each properties of your class, that's how the model binder is working, it is looking for the name of the properties of your class. So depends on the structure of your `document` class, one of the following should works in your case:

```
formData.append('Id', document.Id)
formData.append('Name', document.Name)
```

Or this:

```
formData.append('document', {Id: document.Id, Name: document.Name})
```

Or:

```
formdata.append("document[id]", document.Id)
formdata.append("document[name]", document.Name)
```

And for file you might want to use something like this:

```
formData.append('file', {uri: file, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg'})
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, model binding gets data in the form of key-value pairs, assuming both are strings. Files are an exception.

You can pass key-value pairs like this

```
formData.append('document.title', document.title)
```

Alternatively, you can build a custom model binder. Like it is described in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017720/asp-net-core-and-formdata-binding-with-file-and-json-property/49471824).