# How to pass other parameter with file to ASP.NET Core controller from Angular?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem, I need to pass model as first a parameter, and as the second parameter, I need to pass a file

Adding a file to a form:

```
const formDate = new FormData();
formDate.append("File", this.file);
```

Sending data from angular:

```
this.dataService.createRestaurant(this.restaurant, formDate)
    .subscribe((data: Restaurant) => this.loadProducts(data))
```

Data sending service:

```
createRestaurant(model: Restaurant, form: FormData){
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().append("Content-Disposition", "multipart/form-data")
    return this.http.post(this.url, {model, form}, {headers: headers});
  }
```

Controller in Asp.net core:

```
public IActionResult Post(Restaurant restaurant, IFormFile File)
    {
       code...
    }
```

I tried to solve this problem for two days, the model is transferred normally, but the file is always null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you shape the data into a form

```
const formDate = new FormData();
formDate.append("restaurant", JSON.stringify(this.restaurant));
formDate.append("file", this.file[0], this.file[0].name);
```

"this.restaurant" is exactly the same data model as in Asp.Net Core

Accept json data as in this question:
[ASP.NET Core and formdata binding with file and json property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017720/asp-net-core-and-formdata-binding-with-file-and-json-property)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your action to this:

```
public IActionResult Post(RestaurantViewModel viewModel)
    {
       code...
    }
```

by creating a ViewModel

```
public RestaurantViewModel
{
public Restaurant restaurant {get; set;}
public IFormFile File {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I have tried already, I tried a lot of things, but it didn’t work.

Comment: Did you try add [FromBody] for example?

Comment: Yes, I tryed [FromBody] and [FromForm]

Comment: And I don't know what is Restaurant is, but did you try to append it to the form too?

Comment: And I am not sure that you need to add const headers = new HttpHeaders().append("Content-Disposition", "multipart/form-data") explicitely

Comment: restaurant is a model to which data is added