# Why doesn't Asp.Net Core want to bind data from Angular form?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I form data into a form for angular like this:

```
const formDate = new FormData();
formDate.append("restaurant", JSON.stringify(this.restaurant));
formDate.append("file", this.file[0], this.file[0].name);
```

I can see through the developer panel in the browser that the form is submitting the correct data:
[image]

But the controller accepts such data, and the file arrives normally:
[image]

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
  public IActionResult Post([FromForm]Restaurant restaurant, [FromForm]IFormFile file)
  {
    code...
  }
```

Comment: Are you able to manually POST data to your web api endpoint via postman or fiddler?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017720/asp-net-core-and-formdata-binding-with-file-and-json-property